# How to write a brief description of myself for my first job?

Tags: resume, new-job

I have just started my first job in a company as an engineer, I was asked to write a brief description of myself which will be sent to all the staffs. Could you please provide some template? how we can write an interesting autobiography?
Having said that some humor or random facts can be included in this bio.

Comment: I also wouldn't overthink it too much, as long as you don't talk about your love of BDSM or whatever it's not going to matter much.

Answer (score 2):

As you say in the question, it should be brief.  It should also be professional.

Generally, say who you are, what your professional background is, and then perhaps a sentence or two about you personally.

Something like this:

> My name is Elena93 and I just moved here from Boston.  I have a degree in cake decorating from Boston State, and have done professional cakes for 8 years, specializing in children's birthday cakes.  In my spare time I enjoy bowling and archery with my family, as well as jogging with my dog.

Keep it brief, and keep it professional. If you must make a joke, make it clean and very simple, because humor doesn't always come across professionally.

Comment: They recommended to include images, what kind of images is it good to be included? Is it professional to include an image of me running and say I enjoy running in spare time?  or image of me travelling to other countries, Of course in those images, my clothes do not look like a casual business cloth

Comment: Running picture sounds ideal - much better than a cheesy posed picture, unless they do also need a mugshot?

Comment: @Elena93 Who instructed you to create this brief description? They are far more likely to know exactly what you should put into it than strangers on the internet. Just send them a quick email along the lines of "hey, what kind of images are you looking for in the brief description of myself?"

Comment: Depends on the company and how corporate they are. I would include a profile/headshot. The sort of thing you see on linked in. If it's more of an informal place (which often means smaller, which often means no 'newsletter') then running would be fine. Can you see any previous examples?

Comment: You could also include something cheesy like 'I'm looking forward to ... at company X'

Comment: It is for an inside company newsletter

Comment: @Elena93 can you look at back issues of the company newsletter and see what blurbs they have published about other new employees?

Answer (score 1):

I've been asked to write a few of these over the years and I have always followed the format of: Name, Academic Institution (and accreditation). Excited to be here...what I do outside of work.

> I'm Clark Kent, and I just moved here from Krypton. I attended Fortress of Solitude University, where I obtained a B.A in Journalism specializing in Superhero phenomenon. I look forward to contributing to the Daily Star and adding in anyway I can. When I am not writing or researching I am leaping over tall buildings in a single bound, and flying faster than a speeding bullet.

If a picture is suggested I would use a more personal photo (personally I have actually used my profile picture) if it relevant to your "blurp".

Good luck - and google can be your friend here.